# Why isn't the verb to be used: The house sold for more than expected.

Tags: grammar, differences, middle-voice

I'm trying to understand the construction of these two sentences and would appreciate any help/thoughts:

> 1. The house **sold** for more than expected.
> 2. The house **fetched** more than expected.

To me both sentences seem to convey the same meaning,that is, the value that was obtained after selling the house was greater than expected.

What I'm really trying to determine is why the verb *to be* isn't necessary to form the passive here, in either sentence and whether it has something to do with *sold* and *fetched* being used in an intransitive form.

Comment: The second sentence is not passive.  "The house fetched (money)" and "The dog fetched (a stick)" are both active.

Comment: OK, I see now that sentence 2 is active. So in that same sentence (2) would the direct object be *more than expected* ? Any ideas about sentence 1?

Comment: "more than expected", with "money" implied.

Comment: The first sentence isn't a passive, either. It's the so-called [Middle Construction](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/186066/15299), as in _Her book is selling well_. Normally _sell_ requires an agent subject, but it may appear in this construction as well with a patient subject and no agent expressed. Since this construction is not Passive, it doesn't use the _be_ that Passive would require; there is in fact no marking at all, which is what makes it confusing.

Comment: 'The primitive tribes thought that the explorers ate well' might once have been a cause for concern.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth No, the *ready* question is all about *ready* being able to be both a control adjective and also take hollow clauses. In generative speak that means that *ready* is a tough adjective and an Equi-deletion adjective. Completely different phenomenon. Hence why you might need to be worried if a cannibal said "Are you ready to eat?"

Comment: @Araucaria Agreed. There have been other questions which actually do address the middle voice. eg [This book reads easily vs this book is reading easily](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/220101/this-book-reads-easily-vs-this-book-is-reading-easily).

Answer (score 0):

@John Lawler's answer in the comment:

The first sentence isn't a passive, either. It's the so-called [Middle Construction](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/186028/passive-voice-expressed-by-means-of-the-active-voice/186066#186066), as in

> *Her book is selling well.*

Normally *to sell* requires an agent subject, but it may appear in this construction as well, with a patient subject, and no agent expressed. Since this construction is not Passive, it doesn't use the auxiliary *be* that Passive would require; there is in fact no marking at all, which is what makes it confusing.